# Does the latest Flex SDK support iOS 5.1?

Tags: ios, apache-flex, flex4.6, ios5.1

We developed an iPhone app using Flex SDK 4.6 some months before and it worked fine (although it is slow).

However, today the app cannot be installed after users upgrade to iOS 5.1.

Does the latest/most current Flex SDK support iOS 5.1?

Is there any project has the similar problem?

Is there anyway to handle it?